# Which is the most appropriate hook to set cookies in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, hook

Well, that's the question.
I am thinking in some before that `init` hook. There exists a best option in case of some redirection by another plugin, or any unexpected behavior?

Comment: Why don't you set a cookie with javascript ? And why don't you use Local Storage, which is available since IE8 ?

Comment: I am trying to improve plugins, javascript should be the last option... I talk about some WP hook before `init`.  You should think in implement solutions compatibles with browsers previous to IE8 :)

Comment: `init` seems like the best choice as it is run before any headers are sent.

Comment: @jrod yes, I know about the headers issue, maybe I am too paranoid. Someone with another opinion?